# What will be the IP of the following bridge interface?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, bridge

I have a system that currently has 2 network interfaces, eth0 (ethernet cable) and wlan0 (internal wifi). eth0 interface has IP of 192.168.1.100 which is given by my router and wlan0 has IP of 192.168.2.1 because it shares internet as a hostapd access point to other devices , plus it works as a DHCP/DNS server for them. Now my question is if I create a bridge interface of br0, in order to add wlan0 and eth0 together to eliminate double NAT and have only one internal network instead of two, what the final IP of the br0 will be?

a) an IP from eth0 network, like 192.168.1.x

b) an IP from wlan0 network, like 192.168.2.x

To my understanding, I believe a) is correct but I read somewhere that on a bridge interface, it doesn't matter if you connect wlan0 to eth0 or eth0 to wlan0 so on this logic, b) may also be correct! I am confused!

Answer (score 1):

> if I create a bridge interface of br0, in order to add wlan0 and eth0 together

This actually works in this case because wlan0 is an access point (AP), and you can bridge APs. You cannot bridge a client WLAN (which is a FAQ).

> what the final IP of the br0 will be

It will get whatever it gets assigned. As you bridge eth0 and wlan0, that means they will span a single subnet. There is a DHCP server behind eth0, so this server will react to any DHCP request in either LAN or WLAN. So if you configure your `br0` with DHCP, it will get whatever the DHCP server assigns to it (a 192.168.1.x address).

This also means you can no longer run the DHCP server on this machine, because then you will have two competing DHCP servers for the same subnet. That it turn makes it difficult to provide DNS, as you'll have to configure the DHCP server behind eth0 for that.

If that's not what you want, then route, and don't bridge. This means you also need a route to the WLAN subnet on the gateway behind eth0 (most likely your home router), and that box should also handle NAT in this second subnet. So you may need an open firmware (like OpenWRT) on the home router to configure this.

If your home router doesn't allow this, it will get difficult - avoiding double NAT with off-the-shelf home routers is a PITA.

---

I don't really understand "[main router] acts as a DHCP server from pi-hole itself for this subnet." - usually the main router is part of the the WLAN subnet and then acts a DHCP server via its own WLAN interface. It cannot really act "from the Pi-hole" as a DHCP Server. Also, in that case usually the WLAN interface of the home router is the AP, and you cannot have a second AP on the Pi-hole.

Anyhow, if the router is configured as a DHCP server both on the LAN 192.168.1.x and the WLAN 192.168.2.x, and you bridge them, no matter if on the Pi-hole or somewhere else, no matter where the APs are, then you have two subnet ranges with competing DHCP servers on the same broadcast domain, both of which (two subnet ranges, and competing DHCP servers) is a recipe for chaos. Don't do that.

Also note that you don't "merge subnets as `br0`". You are making a (software) bridge, and that bridge has ports to both subnets, as well as a third internal port called `br0` towards the OS of the box where the bridge runs.

Comment: DHCP server is my main router , 192.168.1.1, which gives 192.168.1.100 to my eth0 interface (system is a raspbery pi, it has both wifi and ethernet interfaces) but also wlan0 interface on the same system has 192.168.2.1 and acts as a DHCP server from pi-hole itself for this subnet. So what will happen when I  merge them as br0? Can it have 192.168.1.x (more external network) or 192.168.2.x (more internal network) address? If I want to eliminate double NAT, 192.168.1.x seems the right solution but I want to hear in what cases we can use the 192.168.2.x one, thanks!

Comment: Also, my main router has  WLAN access, no problem, so all hosts connected to it have 192.168.1.X  ip but I want to just experiment with more sub-networks spawned behind the pi, I also plan to make the 192.168.2.x network work behind a vpn, provided I install openvpn client on pi, so instead of "wlan0 - to - eth0 " routing , I will have "wlan0 - to - tun0" routing, bypassing the 192.168.1.x subnet completely and all wifi guests behind  the wlan0 AP of pi will have external IP of my VPN!

Comment: ok, I will try to draw my current network as accurate as possible to avoid any misunderstandings:                                                     internet -> main router 192.168.1.1 -------(ethernet cable)-----------eth0 of raspberry pi with IP 192.168.1.100.

Comment: Also,       wlan0 of raspberry pi with IP 192.168.2.1 , hostapd  and DHCP server bound  to wlan0 from pi-hole------(wifi network)----other devices which obtain 192.168.2.x address from the DHCP server of pi.

Comment: so yes, my main router is a different device than my system (raspbery pi) with eth0 and wlan0 interfaces. And the wifi I mentioned spawns from wlan0 interface of raspberry pi instead of main router.